# How to find the average price between two specific dates in the past in Google Sheets Finance

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I'm trying to write a formula to give the average price of a stock between two specific dates in the past in Google Sheets Finance, say between October 3rd, 2013 and November 12th, 2013.

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("TSL"; "price"; "2021/10/03"; "2021/11/12"); 
 "offset 1"; 0);;2))
```

[image]

Comment: Does the formula apply for volume too? When I tried it with the "volume" attribute for the stock ticker "LULU" for the period 2008-01-04 to 2008-01-30, it doesn't match the volume data from Investor.com. Oddly, using your formula for volume data for "GOOGL" for the same period, 2008-01-04 to 2008-01-30, looks to be accurate.

Comment: @Nick not all tickers work in GOOGLEFINANCE. also there are some tickers which does not have that long history

Answer (score 0):

First you take data from that period. For example:
=googlefinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD","price","2013-10-03","2013-11-12","daily")

This builds a table where you have all the rates in 2nd column.
Then you have to take only second column using INDEX() formula and take average of it using AVERAGE() formula:

```
=average(index(googlefinance("CURRENCY:EURUSD","price","2013-10-03","2013-11-12","daily"),,2))
```

[image]